# ¿Cómo puedo Imprimir una tabla con información de una lista utilizando fill?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando imprimir una tabla desde una lista utilizando `fill()` del módulo `textwrap`, para limitar la cantidad de caracteres dentro de una de las columnas de la tabla.

Este es mi código:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from textwrap import fill

x = PrettyTable()

column_names = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
lista = ["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"]

x.add_column(column_names[0],[fill(lista,width=10)])
x.add_column(column_names[1], [11111,22222])  
x.add_column(column_names[2], [33333,44444])  
x.add_column(column_names[3], [55555,66666])

print(x)
```

Al ejecutar me encuentro con este error:

> AttributeError: 'list' has no attribute 'expandtabs'

Lo entiendo, sin embargo no encuentro la forma de poder pasarle una lista de forma automática y que este imprima una tabla en orden hacia abajo.

El resultado que busco es lo siguiente:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------ -----+
|     C1     |     C2     |     C3     |     C4     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| aaaaaaaaaa |  11111     |  33333     |  55555     |
| aaaaaaaaaa |            |            |            |
| aa         |            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| bbbbbbbbb  |  22222     |   44444    |    66666   |
| bbbbbbbbb  |            |            |            |
| bbbbbb     |            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Si conocen alguna forma que esto se pueda solucionar se los agradecería.

Comment: `x.add_column(column_names[0],[fill(x, 10) for x in lista])`

Answer (score 1):

La función [`fill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) espera que le pases un único string, le estás dando como argumento una lista. Si quieres convertir todos los textos de la columna en cuestión, tiene que iterar sobre toda la lista. Hay muchas maneras de hacer esto, puedes usar `map()`:

```
x.add_column(column_names[0], list(map(lambda text: fill(text,width = 10),lista)))
```

Esto no coincide con la salida que esperas, que es justificado hacia la izquierda. En este caso tiene que usar el método `align()` sobre la columna:

```
x.align["C1"] = "l"
```